# boost variant with structure as a key in boost::unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map, variant

I have two structures in a boost variant and variant is the key to boost::unordered_map. I am looking at solution to implement a hash and equals method which will take structure in a variant.
Below is a RouteHasher  method implemented(which didnt work runtime(the same key parameters does not fetch the value from the map). How to implement a hash which will take both the members of the structures for the hash?

```
struct v4RouteKey_t
{
   uint8 ipv4[4];
   uint32 val;
}
struct v6RouteKey_t
{
   uint8 ipv6[16];
   uint32 val;
}
typedef boost::variant < v4RouteKey_t, v6RouteKey_t > RouteKey;
typedef boost::unordered_map < RouteKey, RouteValue_t > RouteMap;

struct RouteHasher : public boost::static_visitor<std::size_t>
{
    template<typename T>
    std::size_t operator()(const T& x) const { return boost::hash<T>()(x); }
    std::size_t operator()(const RouteKey& x) const { return 
    boost::apply_visitor(RouteHasher(), x); }
};

struct RouteEquals : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const { return lhs == rhs; }

    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    bool operator()(const T1& lhs, const T2& rhs) const { return false; }

    bool operator()(const RouteKey& lhs, const RouteKey& rhs) const
    { return boost::apply_visitor(RouteEquals(), lhs, rhs); }
};
```

Comment: *"which didnt work"* - why? Compiler error? Runtime error?

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: which standard of c++ are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you implement hash (`boost::hash_value` or `std::hash<>`) and equality for the `v4RouteKey_t` and `v6RouteKey_t` types?

Adding that makes it compile for me:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e46a97fa1421b63)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <cstdint>

struct v4RouteKey_t { 
    boost::array<uint8_t, 4> ipv4; uint32_t val; 
    bool operator==(v4RouteKey_t const& other) const {
        return ipv4 == other.ipv4 && val == other.val;
    };
};
struct v6RouteKey_t { 
    boost::array<uint8_t, 16> ipv6; uint32_t val; 
    bool operator==(v6RouteKey_t const& other) const {
        return ipv6 == other.ipv6 && val == other.val;
    };
};

size_t hash_value(v4RouteKey_t const& key) { return key.val; }
size_t hash_value(v6RouteKey_t const& key) { return key.val; }

struct RouteValue_t {};

typedef boost::variant<v4RouteKey_t, v6RouteKey_t> RouteKey;
typedef boost::unordered_map<RouteKey, RouteValue_t> RouteMap;

int main() {
    RouteMap map;
}
```

### BONUS

A c++17 enabled library/compiler could do all of this without boost:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bac4b40504e5add)</kbd>**

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <numeric>
#include <variant>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

struct v4RouteKey_t { 
    std::array<uint8_t, 4> ipv4; uint32_t val; 

    bool operator==(v4RouteKey_t const& other) const { return std::tie(ipv4, val) == std::tie(other.ipv4, other.val); };
};
struct v6RouteKey_t { 
    std::array<uint8_t, 16> ipv6; uint32_t val; 
    bool operator==(v6RouteKey_t const& other) const { return std::tie(ipv6, val) == std::tie(other.ipv6, other.val); };
};

namespace std {

    template <> struct hash<v4RouteKey_t> {
        size_t operator()(v4RouteKey_t const& key) { 
            return std::accumulate(key.ipv4.begin(), key.ipv4.end(), size_t(key.val), [](size_t seed, uint8_t b) { return (seed*139) ^ b; });
        }
    };
    template <> struct hash<v6RouteKey_t> {
        size_t operator()(v6RouteKey_t const& key) { 
            return std::accumulate(key.ipv6.begin(), key.ipv6.end(), size_t(key.val), [](size_t seed, uint8_t b) { return (seed*139) ^ b; });
        }
    };
}

struct RouteValue_t {};

typedef std::variant<v4RouteKey_t, v6RouteKey_t> RouteKey;
typedef std::unordered_map<RouteKey, RouteValue_t> RouteMap;

int main() {
    RouteMap map;
}
```

Comment: Look like we crossed. You'll need to express the map in terms of the hasher and equals functors.

Comment: Here's a stdlib-only version for modern compilers: http://coliru.stacked-.crooked.com/a/f56acb04035b0c93. Interestingly I had to supply `HashVariant` although cppreference says it should be standard: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/hash

Comment: @RichardHodges Not with my approach  (I had failed to remove the remnants from the code snippet, removed now)

Comment: @RichardHodges You mean Godbolt comes with more complete c++17 support :)

Comment: no, I replaced the static method `hash_value` with `operator()` in the UD hash specialisations.

Comment: @RichardHodges Oh boy. That was silly. Copy/paste strikes again. Thanks